# EXTJS Checkbox showing as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a column that renders based on the value of a previous column in the record.

If the value matches, it should display a checkbox but instead, it's displaying on the grid as [object Object]

Can anyone suggest what I need to add to show this?

```
 ,{id:'review', header: "Acknowledge Review", width: 80, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'review', renderer: function(value, meta, record, id){                            
                              var id = Ext.id();
                              var content = record.data['status'];             
                              if(content.match(/^(VIEWED)$/i))
                              {
                                  var checkBox = new Ext.form.Checkbox({
                                      checked: false                                      
                                  }); //.render(document.body, id);
                                  //checkBox.applyTo('review');
                                  return checkBox;
                              }
                          }}
```

Comment: Well, the code is incomplete - do you need a string (HTML) where instead you have a pointer to an object? Your "renderer" returns the latter.

Comment: I understand that I need to return HTML but I need to attach the checkbox to the specific row/record based on the regex condition. It's a GridPanel - we do not want users to edit the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `[object Object]` because ExtJS uses the returned value as a string (therefore object's `toString` method is called internally).

`renderer` function should return html markup, not javascript object.

For instance, you could try returning something like the following:

```
return '<input type="checkbox">input</input>';
```

Comment: I tried that and it does create a checkbox but it's applying it to all columns. Do you know how I could apply it only to the record I am interested in?

Comment: It should be applied only to that column, i think you meant applying to all rows, in which case use an if and return empty string for rows where you don't want the checkbox